# Control's scroll bar hidden by border element when adjusting window's size

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF window which I have tried to add scrolls bar to, however the scroll bars get overlapped by the `Border` element unless I resize the window exactly.

I have attached some pictures to show you what is happening. Can anyone help me solve this graphical error so that the scroll bars are never overlapped by whatever?

[image: Picture of WPF Window border element overlapping scroll bars]

And here is the code for the WPF window:

```xml
<Window x:Class="TrackerClient.BITDisplayWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="System Status (Built-In Test)" 
        MaxHeight="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}" 
        MaxWidth="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}" 
        Height="450" Width="900" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded" Closed="Window_Closed">

    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=styleScrollViewer}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Column="0">
            <Border Name="m_hostElement" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto" Margin="10" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: It looks like there is something wrong with your `ScrollViewer` style, can you post that? The border seems to be alright unless you override its properties in an implicit style that is not shown here.

Comment: You forgot (?) to include the custom `Style` in your question.